# Custom Template for Edit Pages

Tags: 8, theming

I'm using Adaptive themes in Drupal 8.

I'm trying to have a custom layout for the `node/edit` page, but don't know what to call the layout suggestion.

[image]

What is the page suggestion called?

Comment: I think you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: Yeah, I could, but it'll only apply but it's called correctly.